# Trouble with receiving data from <form>

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, cgi

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/convert_upl" method="post">          
         Name:  <input type="text" name="file_name">
         File:  <input type="file" name="subs_file"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Python (Google App Engine):

```
if self.request.get('file_name'):
                    file_name = self.request.get('file_name')
```

My problem is that I receive no data from file_name text input. I am aware that the trouble is because of it's existence within the form enctype="multipart/form-data" but I don't know how to solve it - I mean how to receive a file and the string from the input with one click of the submit button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it safe to assume you are using properly formatted HTML? you have no < > around your tags....also try passing a string through your form without the multipart/for-data enctype and see if your form code in fact works.

Comment: I am sorry for the look of the code fragments though I coudn't find any help on formating it here - on stackoverflow.

Comment: use the 5th icon with the 1's and 0's

Comment: No < > is intended - the reason is above in my comment.

Comment: thanks for the updated format

Comment: http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Handling-file-uploads-in-App-Engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [uploading](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages.html#Uploading) example code works fine for me.  Have you tried using that code exactly?  Does it work for you, or what problems do you see?

As you'll see, that example has a form with the same encoding you're using:

```
      <form action="/sign" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div><label>Message:</label></div>
        <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
        <div><label>Avatar:</label></div>
        <div><input type="file" name="img"/></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
      </form>
```

it's just a bit more careful in the HTML to properly use `label` tags to display field labels, but that only affect the form's looks when rendered in the browser.

The Python code is also similar to what you show (for the tiny susbset that you do show):

```
def post(self):
    greeting = Greeting()
    if users.get_current_user():
        greeting.author = users.get_current_user()
    greeting.content = self.request.get("content")
    avatar = self.request.get("img")
    greeting.avatar = db.Blob(avatar)
    greeting.put()
    self.redirect('/')
```

and of course the `/sign` URL is directed to the class whose `do_post` method we've just shown.

So, if this code works and yours doesn't, where is the difference?  Not in the part you've shown us, so it must be in some parts you *haven't* shown... can you reproduce the part about this example code from Google working just fine?

Comment: I'm so ashamed... Because of untidiness I was modifing wrong method which body and name were quite similiar to the good one...
Umm sorry and thanks for your effort.

Comment: @user, no shame -- to err is human, and since (believe it or not) most programmers _are_ human, we all err!-)  Spotting, admitting and fixing the errors we inevitably make is the mark of excellence, since it can't be "never make any mistake in the first place";-).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the POST method to send the data but then are trying to get it with the GET method.

instead of

```
self.request.get('file_name')
```

do something like

```
self.request.post('file_name')
```

Comment: Didn't help. Additionaly I receive the file with self.request.get with no problem.

Comment: so are you receiving the file data, or the file name?

Comment: `.get` is a method of the request object seen as a dict-like mapping; it has no relation with the HTTP method in use, GET or POST!

Comment: self.request.get('subs_file') <-- gives me file with data (actually only DATA It's weird but I think It's because of GAE) 
self.request.get('file_name') <-- gives me nothing